# Return list of words with match score > x in fuzzywuzzy Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, fuzzywuzzy

I'm working on a client-side web application and I want to retrieve an answer for a trivia question from the user, but I want to deem it a correct answer even if the spelling is slightly off. I'm wondering if there is a good way of using fuzzywuzzy (when I wrangle the data originally in python) to return a list of words that would have a matching score greater than .9, for instance. So, if  I pass "chicken" and .9 to the function, it returns all words that have a similarity score of over .9 for "chicken" ("chickenn, "chiken", etc.). Any thoughts would be helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a valid use, given that your webapp is casual and just for fun.

If it is for serious business, I think it is better not to use fuzzywuzzy. The first issue here is you have to come up with a pre-determined threshold of match percentage, which can lead to some weird behavior from users' perspective. For example, `fuzz.partial_ratio("he", "she")` has a similarity score of `80` but with a pretty different meaning.

From what I see in similar applications, you can either store a list of accepted words and compare user input with it, eg. `['chicken', 'chickens', 'Chicken', 'Chickens', 'CHICKEN', 'CHICKENS']`.

Or you can do some string cleaning from user input by various Python built-in functions, such as

- `strip()` for trimming whitespaces
- `upper() and lower()` to convert all letters to upper/lowercase

Afterall, it is users' fault for not getting marks if he writes `'ch!cK3n ~:)'`.